# xaringan: Easy way to change aspect ratio?

Tags: r, xaringan

I would like to change the aspect ratio of a xaringan presentation to 16:9. I guess it would be possible if I would create a custom css theme. However, this would be somewhat of an overkill for me.

So, is there any really simple way of doing that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is super easy since it is already implemented. Just include the following in the YAML (in addition to all the other stuff in your YAML):

```
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    nature:
      ratio: '16:9'
```

Here's my default start YAML. Maybe you can tweak that to your desires.

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "Claus<br>UCPH Biostatistics<br>.small[my@email.dk ]"
date: 'Some day 2019'
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: ['default', 'hygge']
    seal: true
    nature:
      ratio: '16:9'
      slideNumberFormat: '%current%' 
      highlightStyle: ir-black
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---
```

Comment: This is super straight forward. Do you have a link where I could look up all the options?

Comment: A good place to start is the [xaringan wiki](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki). Also, since xaringan is based on remark.js you could look up that.

Comment: The wiki looks great. I'll certainly look into that.